# How to redirect user from custom command in Kendo UI for MVC Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid for MVC and I have added a custom command to every row. Now I need to wire the click event to redirect the user to another View using the ID value from the selected row.

This works as is but the ID is hard coded. I need help with dynamically building the redirect:

```
 function editShippment() {


var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');   //get a reference to the grid data 
var record = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); //get a reference to the currently selected row
var shippingHeaderID = record.ShippingHeaderID;
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ShippingLineItemsEdit","Shipping",new {id= 182})"; //hard coded but need the record.ShippingHeaderID inserted here.  
 }
```

Comment: where is the code for adding the custom command to the rows?

Comment: columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("editShippment")).Width(40);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Url.Action` helper to build the main url and then append the id.

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ShippingLineItemsEdit","Shipping")" 
                       + "/" + shippingHeaderID;
```